# Node.js: CSRF is not getting invalidated after use

Tags: node.js, csrf, csrf-token

I am facing a really annoying issue that the `CSRF` security token is not getting invalidated after it has been used.

I tried to submit the form several times with the same values and csrf token but it worked. Whereas, I should have received the `403` error.

```js
import csrf from 'csrf';
import express from 'express';
...

const App = express();

// CSRF tokens
const tokens = new csrf({ cookie: true });
const csrfToken = tokens.secretSync({ saltLength: 128 });

App.use((req, res, next) => {
    ...

    // Validating CSRF token
    if (
        (['get', 'options'].includes(req.method.toLowerCase()) === false) &&
        ! tokens.verify(csrfToken, req.body._csrf) &&
        ! tokens.verify(csrfToken, req.headers['x-csrf-token'])
    ) {
        throw new Error('CSRF: Invalid or missing token');
    }

    req.csrfToken = tokens.create(csrfToken);

    next();
});

...
```

controller.js

```js
const csrfToken = async (req, res) => await res.json({
    csrf: req.csrfToken
});

export {
    csrfToken,
};
```

[image: Sending requests]
[image: Application request log]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I was under the wrong impression that `API's` data submission routes, such as: `POST`, `PUT`, `PATCH`, etc., should also be protected with the `CSRF` token in order to enhance the security, just like posting a form via a browser window.

However, while searching for the answer, I came to know that unlike form submission via a web browser, the api data submission do not require the `csrf` protection as they typically do not rely on the cookies to insure the identity of the user.

If you like to read more then [follow this link to the question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/166724/should-i-use-csrf-protection-on-rest-api-endpoints)